# Error Code: 1060. Not unique table/alias: `table1`

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have researched this issue but I haven't seen it explained very well yet and I want to try get a better understanding of the issue rather than blindly fixing it.

I'm trying to create a new table that is created from a left outer join.

```
CREATE TABLE `JoinTable` as
SELECT Col1, Col2 
FROM Table1, Table2
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2
on Table1.Col1 = Table2.Col1;
```

Could someone please explain why this comes up with the error:
Error Code: 1060. Not unique table/alias: `table1`

Thank you,
Daniel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove , Table2 in  from clause

```
CREATE TABLE `JoinTable` as
SELECT Col1, Col2 
FROM Table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2
on Table1.Col1 = Table2.Col1;
```

and for ambiguity you must esplicit the table name eg:

```
CREATE TABLE `JoinTable` as
SELECT table1.Col1, table2.Col2 
FROM Table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2
on Table1.Col1 = Table2.Col1;
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply!

However doing this results in "Error Code: 1052. Column 'Col1' in field list is ambiguous"

Comment: Thank you very much, its running the query now!